# Centering List in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a little problem with my project. I wanna center a list that has its elements displayed in a horizontal line. I cannot seem to figure out how to center this list properly. I made it so that its size adjusts to the viewport but I can't center it. I tried align, text-align, float, and even position.

P.S. Sorry if I said something wrong, I'm kinda new to html

This is my 'style' code block:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #130228;
  background: linear-gradient(#120228, #050305);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
}

li a {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e1131d;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, #ed4255);
  border-radius: 14px;
  color: #133954;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  padding: 0.4% 1.4%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Jockey One';
  text-selected: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.active {
  margin: bottom;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #468902;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 60%, #68da23);
  background-size: 10%;
  border-radius: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

li a:hover {
  margin: bottom;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #275ea3;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, #9ecfe7);
  background-size: 10%;
  border-radius: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="../index.html">Acasă</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient active">Universul Observabil</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="planets.html">Planete</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="stars.html">Stele</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="galaxies.html">Galaxii</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="astrology.html">Istoria Astrologiei</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @Gendarme Thanks but I already tried those codes. :)

Comment: @Gendarme Well, I think my html skills are the worst. Wheror how do I add the code from here - [https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/]

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but it's worth pointing out that `bottom` is an invalid value for the `margin` property; you need to use a length, for example: `margin: 10px`, for a `10px` margin around all four sides, or `margin-bottom: 10px` for a `10px` margin on the bottom of the element. See: [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) at the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: @DavidThomas My skills are the worst in html but I have to do this for a school project and I am the only "true programmer" in a Math-Informatics class. :)

Comment: And even that doesn't do me any good, I tried and I don't see any changes.

Comment: You can try setting the `li` to `display: inline-block;` then setting `text-align:center` on your `ul`

Comment: @zgood Well, that kinda works, my elements are inline and centered but the text went wild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting you `li` to `display: inline-block` and set you `ul` to `text-align: center;` then move all the margin and padding you have on your `li a` to your `li`.

Like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #130228;
  background: linear-gradient(#120228, #050305);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.4% 1.4%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

li a {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e1131d;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, #ed4255);
  border-radius: 14px;
  color: #133954;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Jockey One';
  text-selected: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.active {
  margin: bottom;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #468902;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 60%, #68da23);
  background-size: 10%;
  border-radius: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

li a:hover {
  margin: bottom;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #275ea3;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, #9ecfe7);
  background-size: 10%;
  border-radius: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="../index.html">Acasă</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient active">Universul Observabil</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="planets.html">Planete</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="stars.html">Stele</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="galaxies.html">Galaxii</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="astrology.html">Istoria Astrologiei</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this works as I wanted but the gradient width modifies. Can you help me?

Comment: Nevermind, I just added some blank spaces to the text of the elements. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the extra styling you have introduced here is causing unexpected results when trying to center the list elements.

Taking the flexbox approach ends up ignoring the margin and padding you added to the anchor elements. I think it would be best for you to start with a simple flexbox layout and then add in your extra styling after the fact.

Here is a simple flexbox layout with your html:

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    div {
      background-color: black;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    li {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="../index.html">Acasă</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient active">Universul Observabil</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="planets.html">Planete</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="stars.html">Stele</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="galaxies.html">Galaxii</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="astrology.html">Istoria Astrologiei</a></li>
    <li><a class="no-select gradient" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, centers well, but text doesn't fit :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is want you are looking for. The best way I like to center most things is with display: grid and place-items: center;

You can do this with as well.

```
ul {
   display: grid; // creates a grid
   place-items: center; // centers content combining align-items and justify-items
   grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr); // this is saying grid make me 7 columns all columns having the width of the container or screen

}
```

Learn more about [grids on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

Grid is also supported across all browsers as well. ([Grid support](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid))

Comment: Every answer from here worked but either the text or the gradient goes wild. idk why

Comment: Thanks by the way

Comment: Check out this [codepen]{https://codepen.io/Alfredoeb9/pen/JxoYmv) it worked just fixed some styling.